# Python notepad and autosaving?

Tags: python

I have been creating a notepad program just for fun. I was wondering how I might create an automatic saving function into my code. Perhaps with a loop and a write to file function?

Here is My notepad code:

```
import argparse, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-w', action='store_true', help='File to write to')
parser.add_argument('-o', action='store_true', help='Open File and Edit')
argument = parser.parse_args()
print('Noteleaf')

if argument.w == True:
    try:
        wF = raw_input('Write File: ')
        w = open(str(wF), 'w')
        w.write(raw_input('-> '))
        w.close()
    except:
        print('\nWrite to File Failed')
        sys.exit()

if argument.o == True:
    try:
        oF = raw_input('Open File: ') 
        o = open(str(oF), 'r')
        print(o.read())
        with open(str(oF), 'a') as addfile:
            addfile.write(raw_input(''))
        o.close()
    except:
        print('\nOpen and Edit Failed')
        sys.exit()

import os, time
time.sleep(2)
os.system('clear')
```

Comment: You never need to check if something `== True`. You can just put `if argument.o`.

Comment: @EliSadoff it is not bad for readability.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI How do you figure? Anyone who is coding will see `if x` and know that means if `x` is truthy.

Comment: @EliSadoff, what if there is a function call that takes in X parameters and returns a boolean, I can do if (function(x,y,z) == True): or waste a variable and store the result, writability vs readability. Have your own choice on certain decisions.

Comment: @EliSadoff it's in the book Clean Code, there are times where you as a programmer need to choose and make the tradeoff

Comment: You can do `if function(x,y,z):`.

Comment: I was taught to never directly compare to a boolean.